# Drawing n balls with replacement and pick at least one ball of each colour

Tags: probability

I know this problem sounds familiar, but it has been a while since I stopped doing probabilities, and I did not find the answer easily by myself or on this site. At the origin, the problem is related to datamasking over a string that contains many alphabets, and we want to be sure that all the alphabets we are using are represented. There is in fact an easy mapping between alphabets and colour of a ball, and so here is the problem:

Given $a_1, \dots, a_m$ balls of colour $1, \dots m$, we want to pick $n$ balls with replacement, with $n \geq m$. What is the probability that all the colours are represented in the sample?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Thanks @JoséCarlosSantos I edited the question, to put some context, but I'm not sure if it's sufficent or not

Comment: Is the order important ? For example is picking a white ball then a black ball different from picking black then white ?

Comment: no, the order is not important

Comment: are the $a_i$'s all different? that makes an important difference ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a:=a_1+\cdots+a_m$ and $p_i=\frac{a_i}{a}$.

Let $X_i$ denote the number of balls picked from color $i$.

To be found is $P(X_1>0,\dots,X_m>0)$.

Here $(X_1,\dots,X_m)$ has [multinomial distribution](http://multinomial%20distribution) with parameters $n$ and $(p_1,\dots,p_m)$ so that in general:$$P(X_1=r_1,\dots,X_m=r_m)=\frac{n!}{r_1!\cdots r_m!}p_1^{r_1}\cdots p_m^{r_m}$$whenever the $r_i$ are nonnegative integers that satisfy $r_1+\cdots+r_m=n$.

It is handsome here to go for $$P(X_1>0,\dots,X_m>0)=1-P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^m\{X_i=0\}\right)$$and to find an expression of the RHS by means of the [principle of inclusion/exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

In this expression we meet terms like $P(X_2=0, X_4=0, X_5=0)=\left(1-p_2-p_4-p_5\right)^n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to avoid the ugly inclusion/exclusion principle, in order to be able to compute this probability efficiently ? Or to have an estimation of this probability very quickly ?

Comment: Not that I know of. Ugly?...It is beautiful ;-) and IMV much better then the ugly summation of the $P(X_1=r_1,\dots,X_m=r_m)$ where the $r_i$ are positive.

Comment: Why $\ P(X_1>0, \dots, X_m > 0 ) = 1 - P( \cup X_i = 0) $ and not $\ = 1- P(\cap X_i = 0) $

Comment: @bm1125 The negation of "$X_1>0\text{ and }\cdots\text{ and }X_m>0$" is "$X_1=0\text{ or }\cdots\text{ or }X_m=0$". It is not "$X_1=0\text{ and }\cdots\text{ and }X_m=0$" as you seem to think.

Comment: Ohh.. that's like $\ P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \dots \cap A_m) = 1- P(A_1^C \cup A_2^C \cup \dots \cup A_m^C) $ ??

Comment: @bm1125 exactly!

Comment: Thank you @drhab